# iOS GPS accuracy, how accurate is the GPS on my iPhone 4?

Tags: ios, gps

I am wondering how accurate should I expect the GPS to be when developing on my iPhone 4? What are the specs?

Comment: This is not a programming question and therefore off topic. Check http://stackexchange.com/sites to find a better fit.

Comment: Possibly. Though, I don't really agree. Anyway thanks Foster for answering. It helped me to get in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html notes that the iPhone 4s supports Assisted GPS and GLONASS. That nearly doubles the number of satellites which aids in both speed of signal acquisition and accuracy. If you are asking for the accuracy in feet, as some GPS receiver vendors advertise, there really isn't one because it depends where you and what kind of obstructions and interference there is.

The mean accuracy of the GLONASS system, is 7-8 NSV with 4.46—7.38 meter precision.